# PERL 5.8.4 Installing DBI Module

Tags: perl, dbi

I am working on Perl "This is perl, v5.8.4 built for Win32" version. How to install DBI Module in it ? I couldnt find any ppm.bat unlike Perl 5.12.3 .

Comment: is there no way to upgrade Perl? 5.8.4 is very old (over 8 years old). Activestate Perl or Strawberry Perl are good options.

Comment: Upgrade Perl. Really, there's no good reason to stick with something so old.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`CPAN`](http://p3rl.org/CPAN) module/command-line utility to interface to CPAN repository of modules. Building and installing `DBI` will require having compiler on your system though. This could be not a problem if you got it along with your Perl, that seems to be not ActiveState distribution, but also might prove to be even more difficult if you're don't have it and not familiar with installing dev-tools on Win32.

For a start just try `cpan -i DBI` in command line.

If you somehow don't have access to shell/command startup file, you can also run `CPAN` module in interactive mode and install `DBI` from there:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install DBI
```

Comment: Only cpan.pm is present while cpan.bat is missing.

Comment: @user762421: `perl -MCPAN -e shell`, then `install DBI` from there.